# Jenkins + nginx reverse proxy on Plesk

Tags: nginx, jenkins, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy, plesk

I'm running Plesk Obsidian on my centOS server and manually installed Jenkins on it. Jenkins is up and running. It can be used by calling http://my-server.de:38080 without any problems. I also created a new subdomain in Plesk (jenkins.my-server.de), which is secured with a lets encrypt certificate.

My idea was to use the nginx reverse proxy to call Jenkins using the new subdomain: https://jenkins.my-server.de. Therefore I disabled the use of Apache in the Plesk Apache & nginx Settings for the subdomain and added the following additional nginx directives in the Plesk web interface:

```
location ~ / {
  proxy_pass          http://localhost:38080;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  proxy_redirect      http://localhost:38080 https://jenkins.my-server.de;
}
```

The problem is, that some sites are working and on other sites I get a 404.

Calling https://jenkins.my-server.de should show me the login page, but I get a 404. Only if I enter https://jenkins.my-server.de/index in the browser, I see the login page.
Calling https://jenkins.my-server.de/manage on the other hand loads the wanted page without error. The page https://jenkins.my-server.de/configureSecurity shows a 404 again and only works if I add /index at the end.

Am I missing something in the nginx settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following configuration is working for me in combination with Plesk.

```
location ^~ / {
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_redirect          http://localhost:38080 https://jenkins.my-server.de;
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:38080;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.my-server.de:50022' always;
}
```